# TLS Client in MSVC++ for localhost:Port

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio, sockets, winsock2

I have a local server which has a REST API running at https://localhost:61000, to which I can send the following Curl request:

```
curl -X POST "https://localhost:61000/users/logout" -H "accept: */*" -H "Locale: en"
```

and it would return me the following response

[image]

In MSVC++ using the `WinSock` and `OpenSSL` library I can get the response code `200` from `google.com` at port `443`, but when I try for localhost at port 61000 I always get a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

```
// Client

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    if ((WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsadata)) == 0) {
        cout << "-WSAStartup Initialized." << endl;
        struct addrinfo hints, * res;
        int sockfd;

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_socktype = 0;// SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = 0;// IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;

        if (getaddrinfo("localhost", "61000", &hints, &res) != 0) {
            cout << "-getaddrinfo unsuccessful." << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }

        if ((sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            cout << "-Unable to create socket." << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }

        if ((connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen)) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cout << "-Connection Established." << endl;
        }

        cout << "-Client connected to: " << res->ai_addr << endl;

        SSL_library_init();
        SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
        SSL_load_error_strings();

        const SSL_METHOD* meth = TLSv1_2_client_method();
        SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);

        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        if (!ssl) {
            printf("Error creating SSL.\n");
            log_ssl();
            return -1;
        }
        sock = SSL_get_fd(ssl);
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);
        int err = SSL_connect(ssl);
        if (err <= 0) {
            printf("Error creating SSL connection.  err=%x\n", err);
            log_ssl();
            fflush(stdout);
            return -1;
        }
        printf("SSL connection using %s\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));

        const char* request = "GET /users HTTPS/1.1\r\n\r\n";
     //SendPacket
        int len = SSL_write(ssl, request, strlen(request));
        if (len < 0) {
            int err = SSL_get_error(ssl, len);
            switch (err) {
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                return 0;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                return 0;
            case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
            case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
            case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
            default:
                return -1;
            }
        }

        //RecvPacket
        len = 100;
        char buf[20000];
        do {
            len = SSL_read(ssl, buf, 100);
            buf[len] = 0;
            printf(buf);
        } while (len > 0);
        if (len < 0) {
            int err = SSL_get_error(ssl, len);
            if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ)
                return 0;
            if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
                return 0;
            if (err == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN || err == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL || err == SSL_ERROR_SSL)
                return -1;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "-WSAStartup Initialization failed." << endl;
        if (WSACleanup() != 0) {
            cout << "-WSACleanup Successful." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "-WSACleanup Failed." << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Response:
[image]

Assuming that the (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error, but I can not figure out how to create the request in right way.

Comment: Https is encrypted protocol, try with http first. That is, start insecure server (with unencryted connections). Or you may try experimenting with libraries that support https connections. Actually it's incredibly hard to write https protocol implementation on your own, a lot of libraries written by professionals try and fail.

Comment: Also, your use of `getaddrinfo()` is wrong. Don't include the `https://` prefix on the hostname, that is why it fails. Just pass in the `localhost` hostname by itself. Also, your `POST` request is slightly malformed. `"charset=utf-8"` is not a valid HTTP header. `charset` is an attribute of the `Content-Type` header: `"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"`. You are also not taking into account that `send()` and `recv()` may not write/read all of the requested bytes in a single go, you need to call them in loops instead until all expected bytes have actually been written/received.

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` works with `localhost`, this is point 2 in my question, and I have already tried `send()` and `recv()` in a loop but the result is always the same. I know `Content-Type` header is malformed, but changing these does not make any difference in the strange output of `recv()`

Comment: @OmChoudhary `getaddrinfo()` works with a hostname only, like `"localhost"`, it does not work with a url, like `"https://localhost"`. That is what my previous comment was pointing out. smitsyn already explained why you are getting garbage from `recv()` - you are not accounting for SSL/TLS that HTTPS uses, you are sending a faulty SSL/TLS handshake and getting back an SSL/TLS error. Use unencrypted HTTP instead, or else implement the SSL/TLS portion, such as by using the OpenSSL library, or Microsoft's SChannel API. Or, chuck this code and use libCurl instead, or Microsoft's WinInet/WinHTTP API

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I have updated the code, now I am using `OpenSSL` library, and it works for the `google.com` at port `443` but not for  `localhost:port`

Comment: @OmChoudhary your HTTP request is incomplete. You are missing the `Host` header, which is required in HTTP 1.1: `const char* request = "GET /users HTTPS/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n";`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: **SUCCESS** , please write as an answer, thank you very much